# How to aggregate the daily temperature data into weekly data?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to aggregate the daily temperature data into weekly data. Currently it uses three SELECT statements. Is there any way to combine them into one?

```
CREATE TABLE dailyX (
    city    INTEGER,    -- Index of city
    day          DATE,                          -- Date in yyyymmdd format
    first        FLOAT,                         -- first temperature reading for the day
    high         BINARY_DOUBLE,                 -- High temperature
    low          BINARY_DOUBLE,                 -- Low temperature
    last        FLOAT,                          -- Last temperature reading for the day
    count   INTEGER                             -- Number of readings
);
```

This stmt sums up the daily data into weekly time frame by finding the highest and lowest temperature for the week, and then summing up the number of readings.

```
SELECT city,to_char(day,'iw'), max(high), min(low), sum(NVL(count,0))
           FROM dailyX
          WHERE day > to_date(20140101,'YYYYMMDD')
       GROUP BY city,to_char(day,'iw');
```

This stmt find the very first reading of the week which will usually be the first reading on Monday.

```
select p_city,p_week,p_first
           FROM (select city p_city, to_char(day,'iw') p_week,first p_first,
                        rank() over (partition by city,to_char(day,'iw') order by day ASC) as RNK from dailyX
                  where day > to_date(20140101,'YYYYMMDD'))
          where RNK=1;
```

This stmt finds the very last reading of the week which will usually be the last reading on Friday.

```
select p_city,p_week,p_last
           FROM (select city p_city, to_char(day,'iw') p_week,last p_last,
                        rank() over (partition by city,to_char(day,'iw') order by day DESC) as RNK from dailyX
                  where day > to_date(20140101,'YYYYMMDD'))
          where RNK=1;
```

Comment: where startday > DATE AND DATE < endday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `keep`:

```
SELECT city, to_char(day,'iw'), max(high), min(low), sum(NVL(count,0)),
       max(first) keep (dense_rank first order by day) as first,
       max(last) keep (dense_rank last order by day) as last
FROM dailyX
WHERE day > to_date(20140101,'YYYYMMDD')
GROUP BY city, to_char(day,'iw');
```

Comment: that is the right answer. needed small correction
max(first) and max(last), not max(p_first) and  max(p_last)